# Find the user who increased their hours streamed from the previous calendar month

Tags: mysql, sql

This table is a "heartbeat" tracking event where one row is genereated each minute for each streamer while that streamer is live. If a streamer is live for 60 minutes, 60 rows would be generated in this table

```
Create Table minute_streamed
(
     time_minute datetime ,
     username varchar(50) ,
     category varchar(50) ,
     concurrent_viewers int
)
    
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-18 12:00:00', 'alex','Fornite',125) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-18 12:01:00', 'alex','Fornite',130) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-19 15:30:00', 'jamie','Just Chatting',13) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-19 15:31:00', 'jamie','Food & Drink',15) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-20 10:30:00', 'rick','Call of Duty: Black Ops',150) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-20 10:31:00', 'rick','Call of Duty: Modern Warfare',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-21 09:30:00', 'rick','Fornite',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-20 10:31:00', 'rick','Call of Duty: Modern Warfare',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-21 09:30:00', 'rick','Fornite',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-20 10:31:00', 'jamie','Call of Duty: Modern Warfare',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-21 09:30:00', 'jamie','Fornite',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-18 12:00:00', 'alex','Fornite',125) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-18 12:01:00', 'alex','Fornite',130) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-06-18 14:00:00', 'alex','Fornite',120) ;
```

Alex has two entries in March. That means he streamed for 2 minutes. So, his hourly streamed for March will be 2/60.

I am trying to write a query: For each calendar month, output the list of streamers, who increased their hours streamed from the **previous** calendar month

For example, Alex has two entries for March, two entries for April, and one entry for June. So he streamed 2 minutes in March (because he has two entries), 2 minutes in April and 1 minute in June. I want to compare his last month, which is June and the previous calendar month. In this case, the previous calendar month is May, which Alex did not stream. So I need to say that he did not stream in May and he streamed in June. So, he increased his streaming compare to the previous calendar month

This my code below, but I want to compare the current streaming hour with the previous calendar month. Can you please help modify my query?

```
select
     *
from(   
select
    *
    ,lag(total_monthly_hours,1) over(partition by username order by year,month) as prev_month
from(   
select
     username
    ,year(time_minute) as year
    ,month(time_minute) as month
    ,count(*)/60 as total_monthly_hours
from minute_streamed
group by year(time_minute), month(time_minute), username
order by month(time_minute) desc ) as temp ) as temp2
where total_monthly_hours > prev_month
```

Comment: _Small Point_ Why is `concurrent_viewers` a column you only load integers into, defined as a VARCHAR?

Comment: What does 2/60 mean?  I don't follow your example for Alex.

Comment: Please ignore concurrent_viewers @RiggsFolly. For Alex, he has two entries in March. MEaning he streamed 2 minutes. So his hourly stream for March will be 2 minutes / 60minutes(1 hour)

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: no need a primary key

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to compare both the previous value and the previous time period.  One way to do this is to calculate a "number of months" by multiplying the year by 12 and adding in the month number.  Then you can see if the `lag()` is getting the value from the previous row:

```
select uym.*
from (select uym.*,
             lag(total_monthly_hours) over (partition by username order by year, month) as prev_total_monthly_hours,
             lag(month_cnt) over (partition by username order by year, month) as prev_month_cnt
      from (select username,
                   year(time_minute) as year,
                   month(time_minute) as month,
                   year(time_minute) * 12 + month(time_minute) as month_cnt,
                   count(*)/60 as total_monthly_hours
            from minute_streamed
            group by year(time_minute), month(time_minute), username, month_cnt
           ) uym
     ) uym
where prev_month_cnt is null or
      prev_month_cnt <> month_cnt - 1 or
      (prev_month_cnt = month_cnt - 1 and prev_total_monthly_hours < total_monthly_hours);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7e64f16c500d71ab0952f08a4aef1f1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: not exactly. Let's take Username=Alex as an example, he has two entries for March, two entries for April, and one entry for June. So he streamed 2 minutes in March (because he has two entries), 2 minutes in April and 1 minute in June. I want to compare his last month, which is June and the previous calendar month. In this case, the previous calendar month is May, which Alex did not stream. So I need to say that he did not stream in May and he streamed in June. So, he increased his streaming compare to the previous calendar month.

Comment: Did you look at the db<>fiddle?  This does what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes, I did. I am a bit confused with the column 'prev_month_cnt'. Also, For Alex, April entry is not shown. Do you display Alex April entry in 'prev_month_cnt' column? Please further explain your solution

Comment: @Eren . . . In April, Alex has two views which is the same as March so it doesn't meet the condition.  You could use `<=` if you wanted to allow equality as well.

Comment: the number of views is not what we are looking for here. I want to compare his current hourly stream to the previous calendar month for each month. Even though Alex does not have a view in May, how I compare his last view (which is June) with the previous calendar month (May).

Comment: @Eren . . . This uses the *your* formula for `total_monthly_hours`.  Put in whatever formula you want, if that is not the formula you want.  I think this answers your question.